# Tridion Core Service and Windows 8/Metro Apps

Tags: core-service, 2013

Has anyone tried yet building a Windows 8 App that uses the Tridion Core Service? If I try to add a reference to Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll Visual Studio complains that

> A reference to 'CoreService.dll' could not be added. The project targets .NETCore while the file reference targets .NETFramework. This is not a supported scenario.

Would I have to build my own CoreService reference instead (at a guess, I'd say yes) or is there a better way to use this reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, Metro apps cannot reference full .NET 4 assemblies. You should be able to create a service reference and use the resulting client instead, though.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the Core Service client for metro apps, you can try following methods:

1) Add Service Reference to Core Service and use the resulting Visual Studio Client

2) Use svcutil.exe in VS Cmd Tool to create a proxy class for Core Service client

3) Try to explore the Channel Factory per your use

Answer (score 3):

Or you can get hold of the Coreserivce Dll from 2013 which compiles on .net 4.5 :)